# Change a thread argument python?

Tags: python, multithreading

Hello python newbie with a question.  So I've got a function that queries a device for its state and waits for a specific response, then takes a screen shot.

```
def waitTrig(filename):
    while(True):
        trig = my_instrument.query(':TRIGger:STATE?')
        t = unicode('TRIG\n')
        if trig == t:
            print trig
            captureScreen(filename)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            pass
    return 'TRIGED'
```

I then made this a thread so it could run while I'm doing some other stuff.  The code below is in another py file that imports a py file with the function, I don't think that matters much but anyways.

```
    waitTrigThread = threading.Thread(target=tek.waitTrig ,args=['EUREKA'])
    waitTrigThread.run()
```

I check with an isAlive() after the while loop is broken and the screenshot is taken and it returns false.  I was wondering if its possible to run the thread again, but with a different argument (saved screenshot filename).

One potential solution I can see is having the filename be a variable and pass zero arguments, then just change the variable before I run the thread again, but this seems less than ideal and I don't even know if it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a new thread. I'd recommend having a function to create the threads like this:

```
def waitTrigThreadMaker(argForWaitTrig):
    """Makes a thread with the given arg and waits for it to finish"""
    waitTrigThread = threading.Thread(target=tek.waitTrig ,args=[argForWaitTrig])
    waitTrigThread.run()
    waitTrigThread.join()
```

If you want other things to run while the thread executes then you can do something like this:

```
def waitTrigThreadMaker(argForWaitTrig):
    """Returns thread for the given arg"""
    waitTrigThread = threading.Thread(target=tek.waitTrig ,args=[argForWaitTrig])
    waitTrigThread.run()
    return waitTrigThread

def waitTrigThreadJoiner(threadList):
    """Joins all threads"""
    for myThread in threadList:
        myThread.join()
```

This code would then be used like this:

```
threadList = list()
for myData in myDataList:
    threadList.append(waitTrigThreadMaker(myData))
#whatever other code you want to run as the threads are working
waitTrigThreadJoiner(threadList)
```

Use the first block of code if you cannot run the threads concurrently and use the second block of code if you can run the threads concurrently.

Comment: ahhhh, I thought about doing that but, thought it would be bad to have a bajillion threads that are just sitting there dead.  But I'm under the impression  that the .join() function will destroy the thread thanks

Comment: Using ``join`` is not needed to clean up threads - the underlying resource is cleaned up by the ``Thread`` object automatically when no longer alive. However, if you keep a reference to the ``Thread`` objects, e.g. in a list as shown here, you must remove the reference to allow freeing memory.

Answer (score 0):

just run it again?

```
waitTrigThread = threading.Thread(target=tek.waitTrig ,args=['EUREKA 1'])
waitTrigThread.run()
waitTrigThread.join()

waitTrigThread = threading.Thread(target=tek.waitTrig ,args=['EUREKA 2'])
waitTrigThread.run()
waitTrigThread.join()

waitTrigThread = threading.Thread(target=tek.waitTrig ,args=['EUREKA 3'])
waitTrigThread.run()
waitTrigThread.join()
```